# Laravel get url on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

can you help me?

if in laravel we want to get a variable in url so in route we must wrote like this:

```
Route::get('myweb/article/{article_id}','Controller/ArticleController@show');
```

it will generate like this

```
www.myweb.com/article/1
```

and in controller we can get ID with this:

```
public static function show(){
   list($article_id) = func_get_args();
}
```

how about if i want url like this:

```
www.myweb.com/article-1   // assume 1 is article_id
```

how i must write line in routes.php? and how to get the ID in controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
Route::get('myweb/article-{article_id}','Controller/ArticleController@show');
```

Comment: thanks sir !!, im new in laravel so i choose to asking someone first. its awesome. nice job sir.

Comment: oh sure, i did it.